# Java DB - Why can't I create this table with these foreign key constraints?

Tags: sql, javadb

I am trying to create three tables:

**Users**

- username
- userID

**Categories**

- category
- categoryID
- userID *(references user table)*

**Expenses**

- amount
- date
- expenseID
- categoryID *(references category table)* **NOT WORKING!**
- userID *(references user table)* **NOT WORKING!**

Here is the code of my create statements. Everything worked fine until I added the "ON DELETE..." clauses to the expenses table.

```java
private final static String createUsersTable = 
"CREATE TABLE users ("+
     "userID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), "+
     "username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE " +
")";
private final static String createCategoriesTable = 
    "CREATE TABLE categories ("+
    "categoryID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), "+
    "category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, " +
    "userID INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
    "FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users (userID) ON DELETE CASCADE"+
")";
private final static String createExpensesTable =
    "CREATE TABLE expenses ("+
    "expenseID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), "+
    "amount INTEGER NOT NULL, "+
    "date VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "+
    "categoryID INTEGER, "+
    "userID INTEGER NOT NULL, "+
    "FOREIGN KEY (categoryID) REFERENCES categories (categoryID) ON DELETE SET NULL, "+
    "FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users (userID) ON DELETE CASCADE"+
")";
```

This is the exception that I get when I try to create the table:

> > java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Foreign  Key 'SQL110915104641092' is invalid because 'The table cannot be defined as a dependent of table ME.USERS because of delete rule restrictions. (The relationship causes the table to be delete-connected to the indicated table through multiple relationships and the delete rule of the existing relationship is SET NULL.).  '.

I must be missing something fundamental about SQL databases. What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expenses` refers to `categories`, which refers to `users`. So having a foreign key for `users` in `expenses` is redundant. I believe that the error comes from conflicting actions between `SET NULL` and `CASCADE`.

When you delete a `user`, the `categories` referring to it are deleted (because of the `CASCADE`) and the `categories` foreign key is set to `NULL` in `expenses` (because of the `SET NULL`). But, at the same time, when you delete a `user`, the `expenses` referring to it are deleted (because of the `CASCADE`).

One liner: Remove a `users` foreign key in either `expenses` or `categories`, depending on what you're trying to do with them...

Answer (score 0):

In table `Categories`, in addition to the candidate key on `categoryID`, create a super key on the compound of `categoryID` and `userID`. In table `Expenses`, reference the compound key only.